# Range of a function defined by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, functions, linear-transformations

I am studying vector calculus, and I encountered a question, which I find the solution to this question somewhat colliding with my knowledge of linear algebra.
The question is this. 
Consider the function $f:R^2\rightarrow R^3$ given by $f(x)=Ax$, where A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 
5 & 0 \\
-6 &3
\end{bmatrix} and the vector $x$ in $R^2$ is written as the 2x1 column matrix x=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 
\end{bmatrix}
Describe the range of f.

From what I learned in my linear algebra course, f is a linear transformation with a standard matrix as A, and therefore the range of A is a span of the column vectors of A. So I thought that since the column vectors are linearly independent, the range is a plane in $R^3$ spanned by two vectors (2, 5, -6) and (-1, 0, 3). 
However, the solution manual had a different answer, it said that $$f(x)=(2x_1-x_2, 5x_1, -6x_1+3x_2)$$
and since $$f_3(x_1, x_2)=-6x_1+3x_2=-3(2x_1-x_2)=-3f_1(x_1, x_2)$$
The range of f would be all of $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ in $R^3$ such that $y_3=-3y_1$.

 I am pretty much confused right now...can anybody explain to me about this result?

Comment: perhaps the two answers aren't really different

Comment: Oh....I think I got it. Does it mean that the column space of A is a plane that has a normal  vector of (3, 0, 1)?

Comment: Yes; note that $(2,5,-6)\cdot(3,0,1)=(-1,0,3)\cdot(3,0,1)=0$

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and the solution manual's are different ways of describing the same plane.  Notice that your two spanning vectors (and any linear combination of them) have their third component equal to $-3$ times their first component; that is the solution manual's characterization of vectors in the solution plane.